# Swift3, unable to define a URL with Query Parameters

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Ideally I was expecting my absoluteURL to print

> http://my-MacBook-Pro.local:8080/apis/v2/Driver/driverDetails?domain=123&driver=12&mykey=8908098

From [this](https://www.ralfebert.de/snippets/ios/encoding-nsurl-get-parameters/) blog

But for some reason I am not able to get the full url defined correctly.

**Code**

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string : fullURL)!
for key in getData.allKeys {
   let valueOfKey : String = getData.value(forKey: key as! String) as! String
   print(key as! String + ":" + valueOfKey)
   urlComponents.queryItems?.append(URLQueryItem(name: key as! String, value : valueOfKey))
   //getData.value(forKey: key as! String) as! String?))
}

print("fullurl ->"+urlComponents.url!.debugDescription)
```

**Current Output**

> domain:123 driver:12 mykey:8908098
>
> fullurl->http://my-MacBook-Pro.local:8080/apis/v2/Driver/driverDetails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`urlComponents.queryItems` will initially be `nil`, so `urlComponents.queryItems?.append` won't do anything.  On the next iteration it is still `nil`, so again the append won't happen and so on.

You need to build your own array of `URLQueryItem` and just assign it once you are done:

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string : fullURL)!
var queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()

for key in getData.allKeys {
    let valueOfKey = getData.value(forKey: key as! String) as! String
    queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: key as! String, value : valueOfKey))
}

urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems
print("fullurl ->"+urlComponents.url!.debugDescription)
```

Comment: You should really look at your `getData` structure; there shouldn't be a need for so much force down casting.

Comment: Once I get this to work consistently I'll refactor. For now, all is hell with this Swift nonsense. 1. the http url wont reach my localhost tomcat even though safari on the simulator can reach it. 2. this particular code just `Test Succeeded` at `let valueOfKey =` line. Does not execute the rest of the lines at all. Crazy, it worked two times and now its just crashing i think, leaving me with a log file full of unreadable nonsense.. :)

Comment: You have lots of force down casting; this is a recipe for crashes.  Code defensively using conditional unwrapping.  If your local tomcat server doesn't have a valid SSL certificate and you can't use SSL, make sure you have disabled ATS via your info.plist

Comment: ` var parameters = [String:String]()
        parameters["domainOrGroupId"] = "5"
        parameters["driverId"] = "2"
        parameters["authKey"] = "ABCD" let queryItems = getData.map() {URLQueryItem.init(name: $0, value: $1)}
        urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems` also crashs..

Comment: trying that info.plist thing.. not working. . but can only test after the test starts to work again

Comment: What is the crash?  You probably want `URLQueryItem(name: $0, value: $1)`.

Comment: I am trying to do what you recommended in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944625/loop-through-a-dictionary-in-swift